# Merging functions with properties on a prototype using Object.create()

Tags: javascript

```
var blah = (function(){

    function ret(){

    }

    ret.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, { 
        getone: {
            get: function() { return 1; }
        },
        funcstuff: function(){ console.log('funcstuff'); }
    });

    return ret;

})();

var b = new blah();

console.log(b.getone); // 1

b.funcstuff(); // Uncaught TypeError: Property 'funcstuff' 
               // of object #<Object> is not a function
```

I would like to know the correct syntax for adding `funcstuff` to the `ret` prototype using `Object.create()` above.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qy9Vm/

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Why not just add methods to blah.prototype?  Why do you need to use `Object.create()` just to add methods to a prototype?

Comment: @jfriend00 Because I want to add a lot of properties and methods. I don't want to do an `Object.defineProperty()` foreach property after I've defined the methods.

Comment: @jfriend00: Not for the getter for `getone`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder was jfriend00's answer not valid? Didn't get time to try it out...

Comment: @Johan: Not for `getone`, because it didn't define the getter function correctly. To do that, with ECMAScript5 you have to use `Object.create`, `Object.defineProperty`, or `Object.defineProperties`. ECMAScript6 may define a literal syntax for it, but for now, we have to use those for any special features of properties.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As I thought then, thank you for elaborating. Never heard of `Object.defineProperties`. Would it be more suitable here?

Comment: @Johan: In the use-case you've shown, it doesn't really matter. But I'd've gone with it, yeah: `Object.defineProperties(ret.prototype, { /* ...the property descriptors... */});` I avoid ever assigning a *new* object to the `prototype` of a constructor function except in very limited situations. I prefer just to augment the default object there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know the correct syntax for adding funcstuff to the ret prototype using Object.create() above.

Since the object you give to [`Object.create`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) to define the properties is a [property descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.5), if you want `funcstuff` to actually *be* a function, you define it as the `value` property in the descriptor:

```
ret.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, { 
    getone: {
        get: function() { return 1; }
    },
    funcstuff: {                                       // changes
        value: function(){ console.log('funcstuff'); } // changes
    }                                                  // changes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
var blah = (function(){

function ret(){

}

ret.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, { 
    getone: {
        get: function() { return 1; }
    },
    funcstuff: { value: function(){ console.log('funcstuff'); } }
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});

return ret;

})();

var b = new blah();

console.log(b.getone); // 1

b.funcstuff();
```

`Object.create()` doesn't accept functions or properties directly, it takes a *property descriptor* which is itself an object that has standard properties that can be set like `configurable`, `enumerable` ... etc.

Comment: Sorry for the edits @Sniffer.  I did that by mistake and then tried to put it back the way it was.